# Creating an Tic Tac Toe Grid in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, sprite-kit

Hi Im trying to make Tic Tac Toe in swift and in my setting up of the grid I run into a SIGBRT error with this code:

```
func setUp() {
    for i in -1...1 {
        let XO = SKSpriteNode()
        XO.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width / 3 - 30, height: self.frame.size.width / 3 - 30)
        let W = XO.frame.size.width / 2 - 5
        let y = W * CGFloat(i)
        for j in -1...1 {
                let x = W * CGFloat(j)
                XO.name = "Blank"
                XO.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2 + x, y: self.frame.size.height / 2 + y)
                XO.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "X")
                self.addChild(XO) // error traced back to here
            }
    }
}
```

Has anyone have any ideas how i might solve it??

Comment: You should create the SKSpriteNode inside the inner loop, otherwise the same node is added 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying:

```
func setUp() {
    for i in -1...1 {
        let XO = SKSpriteNode()
        for j in -1...1 {
            self.addChild(XO) // error traced back to here
        }
    }
}
```

So the first time thru the `j` loop you `addChild(XO)`, and then the second time thru the `j` loop you try to `addChild(XO)` again — the very same XO. You cannot add an already added child, so kaboom.

Comment: Thank you very much